# TBB concurrent_vector with openmp

Tags: c++, openmp, tbb

Can we use TBB concurrent_vector with openmp?

Will concurrent updates be allowed?

Comment: I think the answer is yes. Though I can't cite the source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, TBB's concurrent data structures are meant to be thread-safe, which means whatever threading paradigms, such as OpenMP, TBB, Cilk, PPL, and etc, are okay to use TBB's concurrent data structures. This is because `concurrent_vector` is simply a data structure class rather than threading-related control code.

Furthermore, TBB's mutex can be also used within OpenMP, Cilk, and PPL.

Answer (score 4):

Per Section 1.11 of the [concurrent_vector page](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/wiki/index.php?title=Concurrent_Vector#Concurrent_Operations) on the Intel site, incremental growth, limited growth, and *pushing* of new objects onto the vector are all thread-safe operations.

The introduction also says that adding new elements does not invalidate existing iterators.

All these combined mean that you should be able to safely multithread access to the concurrent_vector with openmp.